# Validity of L'Hospital rule in a specific case

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

**Question :** Evaluate the following limit $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\log_{\sin^2(x)}\cos(x)}{\log_{\sin^2\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)}\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}$$

**My Attempt :**

$$ \frac{\ln \cos x}{\ln \cos\frac{x}{2}}\cdot \frac{\ln \sin^2(\frac{x^2}{2})}{\ln \sin^2 x} $$

so can you (always) apply L'Hospital rule to $\frac{0}{0}\cdot\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ separately on each indeterminate form or is there any contradiction...

Comment: Why not? If you find (by L'Hospital or whatever method) that $\lim_af=b$ and $\lim_ag=c,$ then for sure $\lim_a(fg)=bc.$

Comment: The answer is 8? I calculated by just the way describe. Please wait a minute since I can't write for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not? If you find (by L'Hospital or whatever method) that $\lim_af=b$ and $\lim_ag=c,$ then for sure $\lim_a(fg)=bc.$

Note however that you don't really need L'Hospital here: as $x\to0,$
$$\ln\cos x\sim-\frac{x^2}2$$ and
$$\ln\sin^2x\sim\ln x^2,$$
hence
$$\frac{\ln \cos x}{\ln \cos\frac x2}\sim
\frac{-\frac{x^2}2}{-\frac{(x/2)^2}2}=4$$
and
$$ \frac{\ln \sin^2(\frac{x^2}2)}{\ln \sin^2 x}\sim\frac{\ln (\frac{x^2}2)^2}{\ln x^2}
\sim\frac{\ln x^4}{\ln x^2}=2.$$